# Bash scripts looping through files on hdfs

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I have a simple bash script..to concatenate all file paths on HDFS into one variable, I have come up with below codes:

```
for filename in `hdfs dfs -ls /user/kmob/ctp_modules/conf | awk '{print $NF}'  |  tr '\n' ' '`
do
echo $filename;
$var=$var','$filename;
done
```

but I can't get all file variables, into $var

```
/user/kmob/ctp_modules/conf/hive_meta_ddl.hql
-bash: =,/user/kmob/ctp_modules/conf/hive_meta_ddl.hql: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is this exactly `$var=$var','$filename;` ? the error comes from this line

Comment: Your whole problem can be reduced to `$var=asdf`.

Comment: See also https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: it should output 'file1,file2,file3' into $var

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for filename in `hdfs dfs -ls /user/kmob/ctp_modules/conf | awk '{print $NF}'  |  tr '\n' ' '`
do
echo $filename
if [ "$var" != "" ];then
var=`echo "${var},${filename}"`
else
var=${filename}
fi
done
echo $var
```